# Why doesn't my compiler recognize certain methods after adding const default to constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project in Unity c#, and I get an error ofwhich I don't understand why he says it.

[image]

Those errors point to the places where I call the method SaveDictionary() and LoadDictionary() in the following file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BinaryDictionary<T>
{

  public BinaryDictionary(string name, string path = FileReadWrite.binPath)
  {
    fileName = name;
    this.path = path;
  }

  protected Dictionary<string, T> dict;
  protected string fileName;
  protected string path;

  protected virtual void LoadDictionary()
  {
    if (dict == null)
    {
      try
      {
        dict = FileReadWrite.GetBinaryFile<Dictionary<string, T>>(fileName, path);
      }
      catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
      {
        Debug.LogWarning(fileName + " not found, making new Dictionary.");
        dict = new Dictionary<string, T>();
      }
    }
  }

  public virtual void SaveDictionary()
  {
    if (dict != null)
    {
      FileReadWrite.SaveBinaryFile(fileName,  path, dict);
    }
  }

  public T GetElement(string key)
  {
    LoadDictionary();

    T toReturn = dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : default(T);

    return toReturn;
  }

  public void AddElement(string key, T value)
  {

    LoadDictionary();

    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
      dict.Add(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
      dict[key] = value;
    }

    SaveDictionary();
  }

  public void RemoveElement(string key)
  {
    LoadDictionary();
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
      dict.Remove(key);
      SaveDictionary();
    }
  }

  public Dictionary<string, T>.KeyCollection GetKeys()
  {
    LoadDictionary();
    return new Dictionary<string, T>(dict).Keys;
  }
  public Dictionary<string, T> GetDictionary()
  {
    LoadDictionary();
    return new Dictionary<string, T>(dict);
  }
}
```

At first those errors didn't show. They appeared when I added the default value FileReadWrite.binPath for parameter "path" in the constructor.

I declared FileReadWrite.binPath as following:

```
public const string binPath = "Other/Bin/";
```

When I remove the default value again (in the constructor) , those errors disappear.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong, or why he says the error in this case?

Comment: It compiles for me, tho I had to remove `FileReadWrite.GetBinaryFile` and `FileReadWrite.SaveBinaryFile` calls, perhaps something wrong with `FileReadWrite`.

Comment: FileReadWrite is a public static class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try not using `FileReadWrite.binPath` as default parameter of your constructor. try this instead:

```
public BinaryDictionary(string name, string path = null)
{
    fileName = name;
    if(path == null)
    {
         this.path = FileReadWrite.binPath;   
    }

}
```

I don't know exact problem but i guess your virtual methods are causing a conflict with your constuctor. (Not sure though, its just a guess)

Comment: restart your Unity Editor and Mono.

Comment: Restarted, and no change (I'm using Visual Studio, not MonoDevelop :) )